# jQuery autocomplete retrieve with an image

Tags: codeigniter

I need some help using autocomplete with an image inside the result (similar to how Facebook's autocomplete works). However, I want to start with the basics... just like a great example which I found here: http://jsfiddle.net/K5q5U/249/

```
    <input id="auto" type="text" />

CSS:

    img { width: 25px; height: 25px; padding-right: 10px;}
    .ui-autocomplete > li { height: 40px; }

JavaScript:

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users",
                data: {
                    filter: request.term,
                    pagesize: 10
                },
                jsonp: "jsonp",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.users, function(el, index) {
                        return {
                            value: el.display_name,
                            avatar: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" +
                                el.email_hash
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li />")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a><img src='" + item.avatar + "' />" + item.value + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
    };    `enter code here` });
```

However, how can I use this to create it like that using localhost? Are there any code examples for jQuery? I'm using the CodeIgniter framework.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_16/How_to%3a_Autocomplete_with_CodeIgniter_and_jQuery) is a nice tutorial for autocomplete using codeigniter framework .Can you also tell me which version of codeigniter that you are using.

Comment: thanks for your reply Sir..but I'll just need very basic and direct sample..is their any way?tnx again--D